# Virus in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, virus

When i compile a new project in Delphi 7 IDE , the MCafee identifies
it as Virus and deletes it .

The virus identified as Generic.dx!gmk and is deleted by the antivirus so no new Exe is created .

How do we resolve this issue ?

Is this a false positive ?

Comment: You might try installing and running one or more other antivirus products, disable McAfee, then see whether the others also report an infection.

Comment: I think this belongs to SuperUser.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accidentally created a virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus)

Answer (score 35):

Two possibilities:

1. False positive. You could submit your app to [VirusTotal](http://www.virustotal.com/) to check it against other AV tools.
2. You're infected with [this virus which targets D7](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/1717-delphi-developer-virus-exposes-weakness-in-anti-virus-defences.html). This would cause Delphi to produce infected EXEs.

Comment: 3. He's trying to write a virus :D

Answer (score 2):

It might a false positive.

One of our new developers (who is also new to Delphi) was experiencing the same thing.
He renamed his "test" project and forms from the default and it stopped being picked up.

I'm guessing somebody did write a virus/trojan in Delphi using the default project and form name and the "pattern" they created made it into the AV databases.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to fix the problem:

- go to /source/rtl  Delphi7. There is a 'makefile' file.
- please make a new dir called  'Lib' on it
- enter command-line (cmd.exe); enter the keyword MAKE and ENTER key
- it'll be recompiled the dcu files on the Lib diretory created.
- back-up delphi7's original Lib dir
- copy override the dcu created
- please test application (http://www.virustotal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Send a false positive submission to McAfee. Here is an article on how to do that: https://kc.mcafee.com/corporate/index?page=content&id=KB85567

They will either fix this problem, or, even if it was a malware (which is unlikely), you will get a reply by McAfee analysts and then know for sure.

Answer (score -3):

Or just update - Delphi 2010 is 100 times better :-)