# Application marked as Virus by Microsoft AV - Unsure what behavior it is finding suspect or what to do to try and get it removed

Tags: .net, windows, antivirus, false-positive

I'm working on a little automation application for a client in DotNet (framework 4.5) and I just got the last version of the application deployed to the client and up and running. However after about a day's worth of use the application got flagged as a Virus by the native Microsoft Antivirus as a threat Trojan:Win32/Azden.ALCL

[image showing virus detection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VTLa.jpg)

I searched around on the web for this specific Virus' triggers and found [this article](https://malwarefixes.com/threats/trojanwin32-azden-acl/) that describes it's behavior and payload. Here are a few of the typical behaviors of the virus as described here:

1. Runs itself on windows startup (My application doesn't do this)
2. Makes a copy of itself under system files (My application doesn't do this)
3. Creates registry entry to start on boot (My application doesn't do this)
4. Deletes non-malicious files in different locations on the PC (My application does delete files - but only in the current directory it is running under)
5. Connects to a remote host to notify attacker and send gathered data (My application doesn't do this - no outgoing or incoming connections happen - ever)

I'm still perplexed as to why it was tagged and marked as malicious and why even this specific virus. I can't find any information on Microsoft's own website about it.

Does anyone know if I can get microsoft to divulge what behaviors it found to be suspect? Or is there any way I can contact them to try and resolve the issue manually?

[Here's a virus total scan of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0CHm.png)

A few of the related threads on stackoverflow that I've found are about delphi and about general AVs, not specifically about Microsoft AV or dotnet - as in my case

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Antivirus False positive in my executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339136/antivirus-false-positive-in-my-executable)

Comment: @tripleee that thread is about a delphi program and it about other AVs, not specifically microsoft AV as it is in my case.

Comment: The accepted answer is for Delphi but there are other answers which are more general. See also the linked duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237534/how-to-prevent-false-positive-virus-alarm-on-my-software