# Program sometimes flagged as virus

Tags: c, antivirus

Why is it that sometimes my program is flagged as a virus for some anti-virus software, when it's not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about [false positives](http://antivirus.about.com/od/antivirusglossary/g/falsepositive.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

May be your program contains some code snippets which are considered as VIRUS code by anti-virus programs.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus protection systems often use heuristic algorithms that may give false postivies sometimes. Maybe your program has a certain set of suspicious function calls, specific low-level instructions or whatnot. Networking is likely to cause an antivirus alarm as well :)