# Software protection / code obfuscation that does not trigger antivirus false positives

Tags: delphi, obfuscation, cracking, software-protection

I'm looking for software protection and/or code obfuscation software like [Oreans Themida](http://www.oreans.com/themida.php), [VSProtect](http://vmpsoft.com/products/vmprotect/), [ASPRotect](http://www.aspack.com/asprotect.html) and similar. However, antivirus false positives is a deal-breaker for me. I cannot inconvenience or scare away our legitimate users. And unfortunately it seems all of the three products mentioned above suffer from this problem.

My *32-bit native (not .NET) Windows application* written in Delphi right now uses custom license managing code, and it works well, however since no code obfuscation is used, cracks are created within hours after each release. So, I'm looking for a product that adds at least some level of protection against crackers and does not create false-positives with antiviruses.

My top priority is non-evasiveness and stability, lack of bugs and antivirus false alarm issues introduced into my software. Level of anti-cracking protection is secondary to that.

Comment: Obfuscators are dependent on the platform.  Are you using .NET?

Comment: @yahia - it should be better than nothing. I understand that security is a trade-off. Non-intrusiveness is primary, security is secondary for me.

Comment: FWIW, my code used to be false alarmed by AVG. After talking to them, they added our code signature to their known good database, and we never got hassle again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll have to roll your own.  The false-positives come from "signatures" matching known malware.  For example, if some malware uses upx to compress, and a scanner finds upx compiled into your app, you may be mis-identified.
You could get a false-positive just because a scanner saw that you are using Delphi (or any other compiler, for that matter).  But the more obscure, the higher confidence that the scanner thinks: "I've found something UNIQUE in here", and cross-references with its catalog of known malware.  ]

If airport security worked like the anti-malware companies, I'd be shot on sight in the airport because I'm a male with brown hair, brown eyes.

If the scanner is lazy enough, you can be flagged for the installer that you use, 3rd-party components that you use, resource strings, "random chance", something to do with the code signing certificate, or the compiler that you use.

Someone will make malware with FireMonkey. Some anti-malware (perhaps more than one) will take note of this.  For some period of time, it will be trouble for FireMonkey apps.

Here is an interesting discussion:
[Accidentally created a virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus)

Comment: Delphi is actually popular with virus writers.  Just writing your app in delphi will make some very LAME virus tools pick you up as a virus. Oh look, it's a bit of System.pas code that was seen in a virus, also seen in your app... And presto.

Answer (score 4):

[Arxan guardIt](http://www.arxan.com/) is meant to work with visual C++ applications, but an enterprising Delphi developer might be able to use it to guard their products. I know of one very popular  commercial application written in Delphi that uses it, but you have to write some tools yourself to convert the Delphi map files and other debug info, into the Visual C++ formats.

If you wish to roll your own, be aware that the task is to be smarter than the hackers, and to build more layers of counter-protections that rely upon each other in some difficult to determine manner, in order to resist crackers successfully.   My personal feeling is that you won't get those people to give you money anyways, so spending your time to keep them from using your software is merely cutting off your nose to spite your face. But if it's your hard work up there on the internet in cracked form, then by all means, keep trying to outdo them.

Note that if you get into advanced techniques, like self-modifying code, you will almost certainly get flagged by some anti-malware detection software, and will need to request to be white-listed.  If you are not prepared to go as far as self-modifying code, then there may be zero point in even trying.  I am unaware of anything that resists straight offline decompiling techniques that does not require self-modifying, just-in-time-repair-and-damage techniques.

Plain old exe decryption techniques that are done once at startup are also extremely easy to bypass and remove completely, once the unencrypted exe is fully loaded in memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm a bit hesitant about products that does not have a demo or trial for download and does not say the price upfront on their web site, and only ask to "contact their sales team". In my experience, this usually means this is out of my league as an "Micro-ISV". Also, lack of Delphi support is a minus...

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could take a look at one called [The Enigma Protector](http://enigmaprotector.com/en/home.html)

The developer is very aware of issues with False Positives and actively engages with AV companies on this issue. Here is what the developer has said about this in one of his forum posts "Starting with Enigma Protector 3.0 no false detections will be appeared with protected files!" [Link to forum post](http://forum.enigmaprotector.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=535)

I have been using this protection since I switched from Ice License a few years ago and have only ever had one problem with a false positive detection. I informed the developer and he contacted Avast right away for me. It was resolved on the very next AV detections update.

The protection has alot of features and a very helpful help file. It uses a marker system for virtualization and when the code in these markers is run it will use a special language known only to the protection system called PCODE on an internal virtual processor.

It has it's own API's and plugins can be written for it. It also includes a Virtual Box for files and the registry, but now I could go on forever.

Chris

Comment: I downloaded the demo, packed my own EXE file, checked with VirusTotal: http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=487cb86e25b1a96dd5ac81c71d088c1bdea43fc5e77033a8c782dcc827b7e6c2-1317772087 12 Antiviruses report all kinds of warnings. I'd say the author is overly optimistic about lack of false positives.

Comment: yes I had forgotten that the Demo version is not immune in this way, I have the fully registered version 3.0

Comment: Are you saying that the fully registered version does not have the false alarm problem I've experienced with the demo?

Comment: Here is the results of a VirusTotal scan on the fully registered version: [link](http://www.virustotal.com/file-scan/report.html?id=37b6aea0544ce5481a7e61d981f5f899dd582d593c8dc7b7bec6fb0d02e4010e-1317774862)

Comment: There is also a new system proposed by the IEEE called the Taggant System which The Enigma Protector has signed up to. The first implementation of this is due for this November so I have read. It aims to stop False Positives by adding a marker into legit packers. You can read more about this [here](http://www.softwareprotection.info/2011/08/antivirus-false-detection-how-to-solve/) and [here](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2390388,00.asp)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at this differently. We use Oreans and had similar issues but skirted around them by signing the executables. The antivirus software take a little longer to look at your application but most will still accept it as virus free if it is digitally signed.

The reason that I am saying this is that protection systems change as do antivirus systems. You could find a system today that successfully passes the antivirus test and tomorrow, when someone releases some spyware encrypted by the same product yours will be marked as a virus.

*Update - There are a couple of isolated ones that still complain but the majority accept the signed one as valid (we get 6 out of 43 flags whereas without signing we had more than half complain)*

Comment: Yeah I checked this out. Definitely a reduction of false positives. But 6 out of 43 antiviruses complaining is clearly unacceptable (I get similar results).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are solutions available. (Disclaimer: I work for a software copy-protection company [Wibu-Systems](http://www.wibu.us)) and I can assure you that CodeMeter doesn't trigger anti-virus systems, nor does it require admin privileges to install. I can also tell you that any home-grown solution will probably be cracked pretty quickly--we have spent years (and so have the other vendors in this space like Arxan, Safe-Net, and Keylok) developing methods to confuse and confound would-be crackers.

Most crackers just use a debugger to set a breakpoint at the license-checking routine (error message or dialog that is presented to the user) and then patch around the assembly-language code at the authentication check (look for something like compare EAX to EBX and change the code to always return true). So they don't need to try to de-obfuscate your code etc. That's why most commercially-available solutions use encryption rather than some kind of authentication/validation checking--encryption can't be patched around. But even an encrypted executable can be memory dumped and rebuilt unless you are pretty sophisticated about how your re-arrange the PE file format and handle key storage and key exchange.

Given that the cost of a commercial-system with all its strengths and benefits (license management, flexibility, cross-platform support, etc) can be quite low, why roll your own? Most people don't write their own installers, since you can use MSFT or InstallShield or NSIS--why write your own licensing and protection solution?

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at your solution. Unfortunately, my software's retail price is $25, I cannot use USB dongles. This also burdens legitimate users too much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you won't get 100% assurance, but I never had problems with [Armadillo](http://www.siliconrealms.com). Secure your exe and sign it with a valid certificate.

Comment: With Armadillo, it's usually the other way around.  Armadillo reacts to being examined, thinking it's being disassembled, and throws an error.  Usually "error unpacking, LP2/LP5".  Then a month later, the antivirus signatures change, or microsoft releases a service pack, and all is well.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your comment. I've been using Armadillo for the past four years and never got a anti virus warning. The only time Armadillo let me down was when we went for the Win7 Logo, but this issue was soon fixed/worked around.

Comment: Does Armadillo directly support Delphi executables?

Comment: The protection is in a virtual Dll which can be accessed through a set of function exports and environment variables. Its not limited to a specific programming language, we also use it to secure a C# project and ActiveX components.

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one as always.

I would say that you should start looking for a product that is applied at compile time rather than after. Packers that pack binaries will always produce a suspicious result since they act much like a virus would.

I believe many of the game protecting schemes like Sonys [SecuROM](https://www2.securom.com/) does this, or at least are starting to do so. But one could argue, that while you're safe on the false positives side of things, the crackers already know how to defeat these mainstream products.

So you need to find that good up-and-coming ringer product.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a hex editor to edit out the headers like 'UPX', etc. The binary doesn't need them, just the tool that unpacks them.