# How to delete this virus from my Delphi 7 Project

Tags: delphi, virus

When i compile a new project in Delphi 7 IDE , then i scan using http://www.virustotal.com my Delphi Project identifies it's ivected 8 Virus:

[image]

I reinstall my Windows OS and check my PC Hardisk using Dual Boot Linux Ubuntu but i can't find virus on my PC.

Please help me :'(

Comment: This is possibly (or even probably) a false alarm.

Comment: Did you format your hard drive and reinstall Windows and Delphi? If so, this almost *has* to be a false alarm.

Comment: If you re-installed from scratch, assume you wiped any malware (it would have to be truly sophisticated to still be there). If you want to keep hunting, [this site](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/download/windows/) can be trusted for downloads. You can also ask for help in their forums.

Comment: question is more suitable for http://superuser.com/, but do you include any 3rd party components or dlls in your project ?

Comment: @AntonioBakula Doesn't sound so suitable for SU. She is compiling the software and thinking why that the virus got in her code. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993671/accidentally-created-a-virus?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

I checked on the name of one of the reported viruses in your screen shot and came up with this description from McAfee:

> This software is not a virus or a Trojan. It is detected as a "potentially unwanted program" 
>   (PUP). PUPs are any piece of software that a reasonably security- or privacy-minded computer 
>   user may want to be informed of and, in some cases, remove. PUPs are often made by a 
>   legitimate corporate entity for some beneficial purpose, but they alter the security state 
>   of the computer on which they are installed, or the privacy posture of the user of the 
>   system, such that most users will want to be aware of them.

It lists aliases for this from other virus detectors, and the list includes "PUA.Win32.Packer.BorlandDelphi" from clamav. I think that may be the answer. Are you compressing your exe? Regardless, this has to do with some characteristic of the Delphi-generated EXE file and not an actual virus or trojan.

Comment: thanks. nice answers. :) 

result on the screenshoot above from my original project without compress or protect source.

and this result from my projetc with compressing and protect source using ASProtect 
 
http://s25.postimg.org/4rr7isqan/Screenshot_1.png

virustotal only detect three  virus called as 

HW32.CDB.D9c2, (Suspicious) - DNAScan, and Heuristic.LooksLike.Win32.Suspicious.C 

what's ??????

can you help me how to detect .dcu file that had been infected by virus on the bin and lib folder?

* sorry for my bad english :D

Answer (score 2):

Is your program using the Indy library? Some virus scanners had signatures including Indy code because there were Trojans that used it.

Comment: Indeed, our software was completely eliminated from some of our clients' machines for the sole fact that they used Indy FTP (We've moved from FTP to HTTP now). Even without using the FTP (just detected its existence), it was obliterated.

Comment: Yeah, it is a shame that Indy's popularity and relative ease of use has caught the eye of many spam/malware authors, causing legitimate Indy-utilizing apps to be put on various blacklists when it is not Indy's fault that it sometimes gets used for malicious purposes.

Comment: @dummzeuch : yeah im using Indy Library. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I see two possibilities:

1. This is a false positive. Your program is doing something that looks like virus behaviour. Only you can tell what your program does.
2. This is a re-infection of the executable you just compiled.

If you have anti-virus software on your computer and other executables are clean, it must be case 1.

What surprises me is why you would upload your program to Virustotal. What's the reason for that? Did something happen that you have not told us?

Comment: because i'm build a small tools for my Website.  if virustotal  identifies it as Virus, my Website got a bad reputation :D

nice answers :) 

thanks..